# Convert java third party object to json with different names

Tags: java, facebook, gson

I am using the facebook sdk and the object field names often differ from their corresponding getters & setters. Because of this I am unable to convert my json objects from frontend to the fb objects with `gson.fromJson`. Is there a convenient way to do this?

e.g. frontend sends request to backend with object:

```
export class Campaign {
    fieldName: string;
}
```

but the fb object looks like this:

```
public class Campaign extends APINode {
  @SerializedName("name")
  private String mName= null;

  public APIRequestUpdate setName (String name) {
      this.setParam("name", name);
      return this;
  }
  public String getFieldName() {
      return mName;
  }
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the Adapter Design Pattern.

Basically, make a class with the correct field names you would like, and you can make functions for "transforming your fields" called "fromFacebookCampaign" and "toFacebookCampaign" where you manually map the corresponding fields.

Comment: I thought about the same but there are simply to many entities in the fb sdk.

Comment: There is no magic way if that is what you are hoping for. If you don't want to write extra code, then you need to change your field names so that it matches Facebook's.